# What is the proper way to transfer from an old iPhone to new one?

Tags: iphone, restore, data-transfer

When I transfer from an old iPhone to a newly purchased one using the auto detect (i.e. hey we found a new iPhone nearby, click to continue), I need to log into all the apps and set up Face ID again, etc. (it's kind of like all the apps are transferred i.e. installed automatically one by one by the OS and the data copied) as opposed to an actual restore from direct copy and I pick up from where I left off.

What do I need to do so it's like I didn't switch phones at all or is this not supported?

Comment: Just restoring an iPhone backup does **not** remember the logged in state of any apps. Just think if someone got ahold of your phone backup. They would have access to everything, possibly even all your usernames/passwords via the Apple Keychain. I figure going thru the login procedure on all my iPhone apps every couple of years when I get a new phone is worth the added security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do I need to do so it's like I didn't switch phones at all or is this not supported?

What you want to do is not feasible.   The reason being is from a security standpoint.  Apps that require a login need to identify the device from which the login is being initiated.

Every device has a unique hardware identifier (a UUID) that’s used in creating authentication tokens. Even the network adapters’ MAC address can be used. Since these values are unique to that device and that device only, new authentication tokens must be generated  generated with these unique identifiers.

The “question” becomes how does Apple’s servers tell whether it’s you with a new phone or a malicious actor trying to steal your accounts.  The answer is that it cannot and thusly, you need to authenticate with your username and password again.

#### TL;DR

The proper way to transfer from one device to another is to use the method(s)  provided by Apple.  There are security considerations that must be taken into account; authentication state  can’t be transferred, so it’ll have to be a manual process where logging in is concerned.